# How to get á,ű,ú characters instead of ?? using JRuby IRB?

Tags: centos, ruby, encoding, special-characters

I need to use the Hungarian chars mentioned in the title, but somehow JRuby doesn't seem to accept those, and shows `??` instead of them.

The OS is Centos 7, but the same thing happens on 6.5.
The system lang is set to `hu_HU.utf8`.
I also set the encoding in .jrubyrc (default_external, default_internal) to UTF-8 then to ISO-8859-2.
The result is the same.

If I use Ruby 2.1.5 then no problems at all. The mentioned chars show up as expected in IRB.

I used rbenv to install both Ruby 2.1.5 and JRuby 1.7.16.1.

Any ideas about how to make it show these Hungarian chars properly?

For example, I get `??rhaj??` instead of `űrhajó` (spaceship in Hungarian).

Comment: Could you add input an (expected) output?

Comment: Hi Utrecht, Thanks for the comment. I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Needed to put this:

```
LC_ALL=hu_HU.utf8
LANG=hu_HU.utf8
```

inside /etc/environment